# How can i get values from a custom type in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

so i'm working o a project with angular / django , and i'm sending my data from django using graphql , in angular i've defined my custom type "TopicType" and i captured the data perfectly but i have a problem with the type , i'm sending the name and the score of topics and i want to get the values separated .
this is my type.ts

```
export type TopicType = {
subreddit : string;
score : number;
}
export type Query = {
all_Topics : TopicType[];
}
```

this is how i capture the data in api-service.ts :

```
public getAllTopic = () =>{
this.apollo.query({
  query: gql`query getTopics{
    allTopics {
      subreddit
      score
    }

  }

  `
}).subscribe(result => {
  this.graphql_topics = result.data as TopicType[];
  console.log(this.graphql_topics)
  return this.graphql_topics;
})
}
```

and this is the result :

[Navigator console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kajws.png)

what i want is to get every topic and score , i've tried : this.graphql_topics[0] **and its not working**

Comment: What do you mean by "get every topic and score"? From your console, `this.graphql_topics` contains the entire dataset. It is an array of objects, and each object contains the keys `subreddit` and `score`. And what do you mean by "get the value separated"? Do you mean, you want an array of all the subreddits, and another array of all the scores?

Comment: @Terry what i was missing is that in my array the first element was another array named :Alltopics so to get into my "Real array " who contains my data i needed to do :this.graphql_topics.allTopics , then get whatever i want thank you anyways !

Comment: Do not edit "solved" into questions. Selecting an answer with the checkbox marks your question solved; whereas if it's closed, then it isn't expected that folks will add answers until and unless it's reopened.

Comment: Oh i didnt knew that , okay !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is saved in a property named `allTopics`. It should be accessed by `this.graphql_topics.allTopics`.

Comment: Yes , exactly just found out lol , Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Just found it nvm : i used this   :

```
this.graphql_topics.allTopics[0].subreddit
```

ect..